# How to call Shell_TurnScreenOn in ShellChromeAPI.dll from C++ (Windows Phone)?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-phone-8

I am trying to write a custom version of a lock screen tile. I tried my best to optimize the speed in C#, it still can't match an app called Lock Screen Native.

So now I want to try C++ and see if it would be the same fast.

C#

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Shell_TurnScreenOn(false);
}

[DllImport("ShellChromeAPI.dll")]
private extern static void Shell_TurnScreenOn(bool value);
```

How do I write it in C++? (As Dllimport doesn't seem to work in Windows Phone.)

Comment: Could you make up your mind, please? Do you have performance problems with your lock screen, or are you having difficulty due to the unsupported `DllImport`?

Comment: @IInspectable If it's not fast enough, there would be transition animation of the start screen tiles.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan LoadLibraryExW. figured it out myself. http://vilic.info/blog/archives/1138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally...

Get the pointer of LoadLibraryExW and then use it to load the dll.

http://vilic.info/blog/archives/1138